# php - mysqli - insert record dont work

Tags: php, mysqli

I do try to insert information into databace with mysqli but it doesn't work!
The command seems to be correct!

```
$creg=mysqli_connect('localhost','uuu','uuu','pro5');
$sqreg="INSERT INTO tbl_users (username,name,lastname,password,email,gender,country,city,register_date,ip1) VALUES('$un','$na','$lnm','$ps','$eml','$ge','$co','$ci','$rdt','$ip')";
if (mysqli_query($creg, $sqreg) ) {

    echo "Create successfully"."<br>";
    echo  $sqreg . "<br>" . mysqli_error($creg);

} else {
     echo "Error: ";
}
```

and this is output

```
Create successfully
INSERT INTO tbl_users (username,name,lastname,password,email,gender,country,city,register_date,ip1) VALUES('dfvdfvd','vfd','dfv','fvdfvd','dfvdfv','1','1','1','0','0')
```

what is the problem?!
thanks

Comment: `if (mysqli_query($creg, $sqreg) ) {

    echo "Create successfully"."<br>";
    echo  $sqreg . "<br>" . mysqli_error($creg);` - um... that error, belongs in the `else{...}` should there be one.

Comment: we have no idea what those variables in values are.

Comment: *"what is the problem?"* - Um, you tell us.  If the code is working, and it's *claiming* that it's working, then why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: and check your connection; you're just assuming you connected successfully.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [**your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Information is not entered in the database

Comment: mysql works fine! mysqli doesn't work

Comment: And the version of your php server (if mysqli doesnt work)... ?

Comment: i have xammp 3.2.2 . how can i find out the php wersion?

Comment: @behzad `$ php -v` cmd/terminal or create a new `php` file and use this code `phpinfo();`

Comment: @Samuel where should i type codes

Comment: @behzad a new php file... save it somewhere in your localhost scope

Comment: @Samuel php version is 5.6.30

Comment: @behzad, again I think its your table structure... look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things which may affect your database query:

1. Test your connection

---

```
<?php 
$creg = mysqli_connect();
if(!$creg) {
  trigger_error('Connection did not work.' .  mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

---

2. **Check your columns** (in your table) and what you are sending to your database

I am pretty sure this would be the reason for you not being able to complete the action. If you are sending wrong column names, or more than your table has, it will simply not add anything.

For instance, you are sending data to these columns:

```
username, # @varchar
name, # @varchar
lastname, # @varchar
password, # @varchar
email, # @varchar
gender, # @varchar
country, # @varchar
city, # @varchar
register_date, # @date
ip1 # @int
```

Now, your table should have those columns, and that they are the right type.

That annoying part is that PHP runs the query as though MySQL took it properly, so it would make sense you are seeing the success message.

So check the query and your table.

You could also share your `table_schema`, that would be helpful in determine the issue.

---

**NOTE**: please, please, please! Look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), they are both more elegant, and just common sense today.

Comment: No problem... That issue can be a pain to fix, because again, PHP will just not tell you something didn't work, so no error_logs, no nothing. It's life tho